# update record with codeigniter active record

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause, updating

In my controller, I am calling a model function with the following:

`$this->sales_model->softdelete_order($this->input->post('ordernumber'));`

what I want to do, in my model is

`update Customer_Order_Summary set Deleted='1' where CustomerOrderID='123'`

where `123` is `$this->input->post('ordernumber')`

My Model syntax is:

```
  function softdelete_order($q){
    $this->db->set('Deleted','1');
    $this->db->where('CustomerOrderID', $q);
    $query = $this->db->update('Customer_Order_Summary');
  }
```

This is not working or outputting any errors.

The model is preloaded and the post information is posting and echoing correctly so purely a model syntax issue I think.

Help appreciated as always.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After

```
$query = $this->db->update('Customer_Order_Summary');
```

add

```
$this->db->last_query();
```

to see your query and you can repair it from there.

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
$this->db->set('Deleted',1);
```

If not working post your exact error